# Wordpress plugin to sell physical courses

Tags: wordpress, plug-in

I need a wordpress plugin that allows me to sell courses in physical locations, such as creating a calendar of cooking courses, which will be done at my house. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

you should have a couple of options for that.

https://woocommerce.com/products/woocommerce-bookings/#

should work for what you need but it is a little pricey.

You could always try https://wordpress.org/plugins/woo-bookings-calendar/ however it isn't very popular but could be worth a test.

(This is my first answer ever so sorry if I missed something.)